# "than do something" vs. "then do something"

Tags: word-usage

Which is sentence is correct? Than? Or Then?

> I'd rather go running **then** eat

Or...

> I'd rather go running **than** eat

Comment: If your question cannot be rephrased into a less offensive question and still be answered, then it is essentially a proofreading request, and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Both sentences are grammatically correct, but they don't mean the same thing.**

---

> I'd rather do A than B.

This means that, instead of doing B, I would prefer to do A. I can do one of two things, and I want to do the first one rather than the second.

---

> I'd rather do A then B.

This means that A and B will be done in sequence: first A, followed by B. The fact that you would *rather* do "A then B" means there was some other course of action you could take instead, either implied or else stated elsewhere. For example, one might say:

> I'd rather sleep then take a walk than take a walk and then go sleep.

Or it could be in the form of a rhetorical question:

> Eat a full meal and then go run? I'd rather go running then eat.